# Best way to handle a validations before a delete?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I need to be to perform validations during the Delete Action in my controller. Does ASP.net MVC3 have anything to assist with this type of validation? I know you can use the Attributes to handle edit validations but what about deletion?

For example i need to check the state of the entity object and if a certain condition is met they are not allowed to delete. What's the best way to check and display an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have your delete action to be like the following, you can check for your condition by making a call like in the example below the method `CanThiBeDeleted()` does, if not then you can add an error to the Model State and send it back to the view, where this error message will be displayed.

```
public ActionResult Delete(string id)
{
    if(!_service.CanThisBeDeleted(id))
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Sorry this cannot be deleted !");
        return View();
    }

    bool isItemDeleted = false;
    isItemDeleted = _service.DeleteItem(id);

    if(isItemDeleted)
    {
        // if deleted send where you want user to go.
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    else
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Delete operation failed.");
        return View();
    }
}
```

your view can have use `@Html.ValidationSummary` to display the errors/warnings you want to display.

Comment: I did something similar but didn't know about the ModelState and ValidationSummary, i think i'll change it to use that.